# can't serialize() form object

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a form, however I'm getting nothing (i.e. "") when I call serialize. What am I doing wrong? How can I serialize thisForm?

Note: I have multiple forms on a page and therefore I find the closest() one to the button that has been clicked.

My code:

```
 $('.searchForFriendButton').click(function(event){
                    var thisForm =  $( this ).closest('form');
}
```

sample output from firebug:

```
>thisForm

Object[form#foundFriendsForm1.form-horizontal.findYourFriendsForm /your-friends/]

>var serialisedForm = $(thisForm).serialize();

undefined

>serialisedForm

""
```

**updated with HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="/your-friends/" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal findYourFriendsForm" id="foundFriendsForm1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="firstname">First name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="your friend's first name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lastname">Last name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="your friend's last name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="school">School</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"><input type="text" class="schoolSearch form-control tt-hint" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; opacity: 1; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" readonly="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" dir="ltr"><input type="text" placeholder="your friend's school" class="schoolSearch form-control tt-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; text-transform: none;">H</pre><div class="tt-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;"><div class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-schoolSearch"><div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">Hawley Infant School NW1 8NJ London United Kingdom</div><div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">Hampstead Parochial Church of England Primary School NW3 6TX London United Kingdom</div><div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">Holy Trinity CofE Primary School, NW3 NW3 5SQ London United Kingdom</div><div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">Holy Trinity and Saint Silas CofE Primary School, NW1 NW1 8DE London United Kingdom</div><div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">Haverstock School NW3 2BQ London United Kingdom</div></div></div></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttonContainer">
                                    <input value="search for friend" class="btn btn-primary pull-right searchForFriendButton">
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: could you show us your form html

Comment: you code seems to be correct. are you sure the `.searchForFriendButton` is in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a name to all of your input elements.

```js
var first = jQuery("#first").serialize();
var second = jQuery("#second").serialize();

jQuery("#first span").html(first);
jQuery("#second span").html(second);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="first">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="test"/>
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="asda"/>
  <br>
  <span></span>
</form>

<form id="second">
  <input type="text" value="test"/>
  <input type="text" value="asda"/>
  <br>
  <span></span>
</form>
```

Comment: indeed... a simple mistake which I've spent hours on. Many thanks eaCe :-/